# find oldest accessed files

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

How can I find, let's say, the 100 oldest accessed files? I've tried the following, but it just prints random accessed files.

```
find /home/you -iname "*.pdf" -atime -100000 -type f | tail -n100
```

Comment: it's not "random". it's any file whose atime is at least 100000 seconds "old". if you want the oldest files, then you have to sort the returned results.

Comment: You need to activate the `atime` option for your filesystem, which is typically done at mount time. Most systems have this deactivated by default to speed up disk reads.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
find /home/you -iname '*.pdf' -printf '%A@ %p\n' | sort -n | head -n 100
```

Comment: I was halfway through posting the same answer. I should memorize more of `find`´s man page :-) Congrats!

Comment: `-printf '%A@ %p\0' ` if you want to be safe, but then you'll have to use a loop instead of `head`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `stat` command

```
stat -c '%X %n' *.pdf | sort -n | head -n100
```

Comment: I'd suggest using `%X` (upper-case) and `sort -n` for reliable sorting.

Comment: @Boldewyn Thanks for the suggestions! I definitely agree, `%X` is a much better alternative.  Learn something new every day.